# .exe Generated by Cygwin not running directly from windows

Tags: cygwin

I compiled and build source code files using the cygwin and gcc and everything went ok , i got the .exe file when i run the file from cygwin like this :

```
./file.exe
```

it runs without problem

but when i try to run it from windows , at first i got the following :

```
The code execution cannot proceed because cygwin1.dll was not found
```

so i download and added the cygwin1.dll to the program directory and then i got the following message :

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).
```

i also tried the 32bit version of cygwin1.dll and i got this :

```
The procedure entry point uname_x could not be located in the dynamic link library
```

so i rolled back to the 64bit version ,but of course still the same problem !

again running it from cygwin worked without problem, but running it from windows not workin , so is there anyway i can run the .exe file in windows without problem !?

Regards

Comment: Why are you not compiling it with a native Windows compiler such as [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)?

Comment: the thing is i usually compile it under linux using gcc and makefile ,but i wanted to build a .exe version of it using cygwin and i was wondering why it is not working ?! is it because cygwin follow linux rules ?! so it it basically not .exe file and it is just .bin executable file  in realty ?

Comment: Not to be a stickler @harrymc but Visual Studio Code is not a compiler.  As far as the point you are making.. Colin Jack.. ?? Is there something from Posix that you need (from Cygwin) that windows doesn't provide via native API?

Comment: please review the my edited comment , regards

Comment: The program you are building is certainly 32 bit.  "The procedure entry point uname_x " is a valid message.  Your dynamic library for cygwin1.dll is probably an older version that doesn't have the uname function in it.. I can't imagine why.. it's pretty basic.  uname is a core posix utility.

Comment: After seeing your updated comment.. I would GUESS that the CYGWIN environment has a different PATH than the windows one.  Search your drive for that DLL (look under your cygwin install dir).. open a command prompt, add that folder to your path.. try to launch your app.  Another way?  Launch the working version from cygwin and use the systeminternals process monitor to see what DLLs it loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CYGWIN environment has a different PATH than the windows one.

1. Search your drive for that DLL (look under your cygwin install dir *first*)..
2. Open a command prompt, add that folder to your path..
3. Try to launch your app.

Another way would be:

1. Launch the working version from cygwin
2. Use the [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see what DLLs it loaded and from where.

Once you have located your DLL, either copy it to the path of your choosing (in the PATH I would hope).. or add that folder to your PATH environment.

Comment: dear @SeñorCMasMas i did as you said and looked for the dll in cygwin directory and i found the cygwin1.dll and added it to the program directory and it did run , thanks a lot mate you saved my day